# Before upgrading a package, how can I know what files will be modified?

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I have to update some machines, but I am using a patched version of linux, and don't want packages to modify specific files.
To be clearer here is a list of the actions I don't want a package to be performing :

```
Modify the boot sequence (modify grub)
Change the init files (init.d)
The kernel image
```

As a consequence I have listed a couple of packages and put them on hold with the following :

```
for package in 'package_list grub2-common...'
do
 echo $package hold|dpkg --set-selections
done
```

I also could add them to /etc/apt/prefences with a -1 priotity but I don't think it is necessary.

I would like to make this process automatic, given a list of files, find all the updating packages that use them and put them on hold. If I could find actions performed by each package without installing it, it would be a great start.

EDIT : using `chattr -i <filelist>.` allows me to block access to some files, but I would rather have a cleaner package oriented aproach to solve my problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `dpkg -S` or `dlocate` will tell you what packages belong to what files. You can then put them on hold. How you do this depends on what package management system you use, of course. Usually people use `apt` or `aptitude`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha seems like something I could make a script from, let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best answer, but if you "don't want packages to modify specific files", you can make those files *immutable* using `chattr -i <filelist>`. So, if I were you, I would consider:

```
find /etc/init.d /boot -type f -exec chattr +i "{}" +
```

After you are done, change `+i` to `-i` (or keep it that way until you need to modify the files). This operation sets/resets the "immutable" bit, which is a special extended attribute specific to Linux. As long as the bit is set, the file cannot be modified or deleted.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it is actually quite nice, but would not solve the problem, I would still get errors/package updates. I will probably use it as a security.

Comment: OK, so the package installers would complain that the file is not writable and possibly therefore exit.  I think there's another answer inolving shadow filesystems. But hopefully a `dpkg` expert will provide you the best answer.